# SQL Server Trace For Trigger Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, trace

I am having a trigger issue resulting in the following error being returned to the updating application (Datalinx WHM is Updating a Sage1000 table):
'A trigger returned a resultset and/or was running with SET NOCOUNT OFF while another outstanding result set was active'

The offending trigger is one of 7 on the table and all currently have SET NOCOUNT ON; set. Disabling and re-enabling the triggers one by one has not turned up anything to conclusively identify which trigger is causing the issue which makes me wonder whether it is the volume of triggers and the time it takes for them to fire causing the problem (I don't know enough to know whether that is feasible?).
Having got nowhere with with the above so far i have turned to SQL trace to try and narrow it down, which leads me to the following question:

I have enabled events for Stored procedures (SP:StmtStarting - SP:StmtCompleted) and errors amongst others (please see below for full list event settings)so i can see the table update and the subsequent error being returned (i Cant attache the trace or an image as a newbie) but it doesn't show the trigger names firing so i know which one is at fault. Are there other events i can select which may help?

Thanks in advance

Trace events selected:
Cursors: CursorClose, CursorExecute, CursorOpen, CursorPrepare
Errors and warnings: Attention, ErrorLog, EventLog, User Error Message
Stored procedures: RPC:Completed, SP:Completed, SP:Starting, SP:StmtCompleted, SP:StmtStarting
TSQL: Exec Prepared SQL, Prepare SQL, SQL:StmtCompleted, SQL:StmtStarting

Comment: 7 triggers on a single table??? Why so many? Would make more sense to combine these triggers so that you have a single trigger update, one for insert and one for delete. Even better would be to get rid of all the triggers but that isn't always possible.

Comment: In profiler, select all of the Stored Procedures and Errors events.  Then run your trace.

Comment: Do any of these seven triggers, by chance, make adjustments to OTHER tables that have triggers that MAY have their NOCOUNT set to OFF?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I have by chance traced it to the number of rows in the order table whose related updates hit the table with the triggers on. Greg- i tried the trace with the other sp events selected but still didn't see what i was looking for. Brian- good suggestion but it's one i have already covered off

Comment: Adding a SET NOCOUNT OFF towards the end of the triggers was the final solution. Having SET NOCOUNT ON at the beginning of the triggers wasn't enough